# How can i write these symbols in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can i write the following symbols in latex?

[image]

Comment: after loading `amsaymb`: `\mathbb{G}_{1}` etc

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with how to load packages in the preamble and how to enter and exit TeX's math mode? If so, load the `amssymb` package in the preamble and type, say, `$\mathbb{G}_1$` somewhere in the body of the document.

Answer (score 4):

If you compile with xelatex or lualatex, you have direct access to unicode system fonts. Here is a sample:

[image: Various Gs]

After you choose a font, you set it as the math font for your document using the  `unicode-math` package command `setmathfont{...}`, and you refer to double-struck symbols (=blackboard symbols) with `symbb{...}`.

[image: TGPM font]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
\[\symbb{G}_1, \symbb{G}_2, \symbb{G}_T\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbb{G}_{T}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't load `mathtools` and `geometry` here. Having them might give the impression they are needed for the result. Alternatively, make clear that only `amssymb` is really necessary. It is obvious to us but not for a beginner.

Comment: @campa Right. I use `mathtools` and `geometry` by default, the reason why there were there.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load at least `amsfonts` or `amssymb` package and use `\mathbb{…}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{G}_1$, $\mathbb{G}_2$, $\mathbb{G}_T$

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, consider using `txfonts` or `pxfonts` for a slightly different appearance:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{G}_1$, $\mathbb{G}_2$, $\mathbb{G}_T$

\end{document}
```